# TMesh - generate 3d shape and calculate normals

Tags: delphi, 3d, firemonkey

i try to understand how 3d works and i have created 3d shape e.g. **cube**.

I fill `mesh.data.VertexBuffer.Vertices` and `mesh.data.IndexBuffer`.
All looks ok on the screen but not the shadows.

I do not understand how i can provide normals for **vertices**? I can think about normals for **triangles** but i cannot imagine for single vertices. One verticle can be shared by multiple triangles, yes or not? E.g. for the cube one corner verticle can be shared by 3 walls.

Maybe my understanding is wrong.

**The question is:**

1. Should i have for the cube only **8 points** as i have now? And use them in indexbuffer.
2. Or i should have separate points for every triangles even if they have same coordinates as other triangles points have, to be able to calculate normals? E.g. for the cube i should have:
   `6 walls * 4 points = 24 points` instead of my current 8 only?

**UPDATE**

[image]

```
unit UnitMain;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Viewport3D, System.Math.Vectors, FMX.Types3D,
  FMX.Controls3D, FMX.Objects3D, FMX.MaterialSources;

type
  TFormCube = class(TForm)
    Viewport3D1: TViewport3D;
    Camera1: TCamera;
    Light1: TLight;
    Mesh1: TMesh;
    LightMaterialSource1: TLightMaterialSource;
    LightMaterialSource2: TLightMaterialSource;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormCube: TFormCube;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TFormCube.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var idx: Integer;
begin
  Mesh1.Data.VertexBuffer.Length:= 8;

  Mesh1.Data.VertexBuffer.Vertices[0]:= Point3d(1, 1, 1);
  Mesh1.Data.VertexBuffer.Vertices[1]:= Point3d(1, -1, 1);
  Mesh1.Data.VertexBuffer.Vertices[2]:= Point3d(-1, -1, 1);
  Mesh1.Data.VertexBuffer.Vertices[3]:= Point3d(-1, 1, 1);

  Mesh1.Data.VertexBuffer.Vertices[4]:= Point3d(1, 1, -1);
  Mesh1.Data.VertexBuffer.Vertices[5]:= Point3d(1, -1, -1);
  Mesh1.Data.VertexBuffer.Vertices[6]:= Point3d(-1, -1, -1);
  Mesh1.Data.VertexBuffer.Vertices[7]:= Point3d(-1, 1, -1);

  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer.Length:= 8*2*3;


  //front
  idx:= 0;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 0]:= 0;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 1]:= 3;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 2]:= 2;

  inc(idx, 3);
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 0]:= 0;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 1]:= 2;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 2]:= 1;

  //right
  inc(idx, 3);
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 0]:= 4;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 1]:= 0;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 2]:= 1;

  inc(idx, 3);
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 0]:= 4;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 1]:= 1;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 2]:= 5;


  //back
  inc(idx, 3);
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 0]:= 7;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 1]:= 4;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 2]:= 5;

  inc(idx, 3);
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 0]:= 7;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 1]:= 5;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 2]:= 6;

  //left
  inc(idx, 3);
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 0]:= 3;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 1]:= 7;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 2]:= 6;

  inc(idx, 3);
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 0]:= 3;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 1]:= 6;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 2]:= 2;

  //top
  inc(idx, 3);
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 0]:= 4;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 1]:= 7;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 2]:= 3;

  inc(idx, 3);
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 0]:= 4;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 1]:= 3;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 2]:= 0;

  //bottom
  inc(idx, 3);
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 0]:= 1;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 1]:= 2;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 2]:= 6;

  inc(idx, 3);
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 0]:= 1;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 1]:= 6;
  Mesh1.Data.IndexBuffer[idx + 2]:= 5;
end;

end.
```

and the dfm

```
object FormCube: TFormCube
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Cube'
  ClientHeight = 823
  ClientWidth = 1166
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Viewport3D1: TViewport3D
    Align = Client
    Camera = Camera1
    Color = claBlack
    Size.Width = 1166.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 823.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    UsingDesignCamera = False
    object Camera1: TCamera
      AngleOfView = 45.000000000000000000
      Position.X = -2.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = -2.000000000000000000
      Position.Z = -10.000000000000000000
      Width = 1.000000000000000000
      Height = 1.000000000000000000
      Depth = 1.000000000000000000
    end
    object Light1: TLight
      Color = claWhite
      LightType = Directional
      SpotCutOff = 180.000000000000000000
      Position.X = -9.222618103027344000
      Position.Y = 2.758471012115479000
      RotationAngle.Y = 21.211906433105470000
      Width = 1.000000000000000000
      Height = 1.000000000000000000
      Depth = 1.000000000000000000
      Quanternion = '(0,-0.184053480625153,0,-0.982916116714478)'
    end
    object Mesh1: TMesh
      Width = 1.000000000000000000
      Height = 1.000000000000000000
      Depth = 1.000000000000000000
      TwoSide = True
      MaterialSource = LightMaterialSource2
    end
    object LightMaterialSource1: TLightMaterialSource
      Diffuse = claRed
      Ambient = claBlue
      Emissive = claGreen
      Specular = claWhite
      Shininess = 30
      Left = 280
      Top = 168
    end
  end
  object LightMaterialSource2: TLightMaterialSource
    Diffuse = claWhite
    Ambient = xFF202020
    Emissive = claNull
    Specular = xFF606060
    Shininess = 30
    Left = 248
    Top = 256
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you added a light source to your scene? Without light source all of the faces of your object are shown without any shading at all. Only when you add at least one light source the proper shading will be calculated.

Comment: I have light on the scene and it is working, but without proper normals (which i do not know how to calc if i have 8 points). All is not properly "shadowed" when i rotate the cube. I must know how to do this for basic cube, as i have more graphics like pipe, torus ....

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (including both .pas and .fmx files)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like **second** option is true.
I have supposed that this is **waste of resources** as much more points are needed.
Instead of **8** points which describe the **qube** good from the first perspective
i need **24** points (`6 walls * 4 points = 24 points`).
After this calculate normals are simple by corssproduct.

The results looks ok now, also for more complicated shapes.

[image: 3d shapes after providing much more points and calculated normals then]

The conclusion confirmed with Blender 2.93, it export 24 points for the cube.

```
<float_array id="Cube-mesh-positions-array" count="24">1 1 1 1 1 -1 1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1</float_array>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right. 3D library performance is impacted significantly by memory usage and bandwidth. Duplication of vertices shared by faces is surely not necessary and will just lead to poor performance. I find it impossible to believe that you would need to do it like this.

Comment: Without one single line of code (or "qode"?) the tags "delphi" and "firemonkey" are of little to no help. Please add an excerpt to either part.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i have checked now how it is done by Embarcadero itself for the cube in the source code and i see that they use also 24 points instead of only 8. But if you know how to do this right, please provide the answer, i am really interested in as i am beginner in the 3d.

Comment: @AmigoJack what code do you need? I do not know how to write normals for 8 points only, then no code. You have reference to firemonkey by `mesh.data.VertexBuffer.Vertices` and `mesh.data.IndexBuffer` adn delphi too.

Comment: If you want some help, make a [mcve] that shows the issue that you are facing. We aren't going to sit down and spend out time trying to reproduce your issue. The onus is on you to make your problem as immediately approachable to us as you can.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan read the question once again. Should i have only 8 points to describe the cube? If yes, then how? Please write the answer with calculated normals. I have answered self that more points are needed. you write it is wrong, show how it should be done properly.

Comment: Fine. Watch me spend my time doing something more immediate.

Comment: As an experienced answerer of questions on this site, I'm giving you advice that I believe will make it more likely that people will answer and help.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i have updated the question, is it more accurate? And maybe you can now provide example how to calculate normals for only 8 points :)

Comment: That's not a [mcve]

Comment: @DavidHeffernan in which point? This is minimal code to generate cube with 8 points only (not 24). Now i need that someone provide normals for it. Or someone that confirm that my answer is ok, and i need 24 points not only 8.

Comment: Right, that looks better now, thank you

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you too. I did not supposed that for such basic question "general" about points and notmals i need to provide example app ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i have confirmed with Blender 2.93 application. It export 24 points for the cube.

Comment: I've just come back to this, I know it was a long time ago, and I'm sorry about my earlier comments, but I am convinced that you are correct, and I was completely wrong.